# I want to update a database table MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

My table is called servicii and has 3 variables : id, nume, pret.
I have this code, but doesn't work.
Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate2']))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE servicii SET nume =?, pret=? WHERE id=?");
    $nume = $_POST['txtNume'];
    $pret = $_POST['txtCantitate'];
    $id = $_POST['selectProd'];
    $stmt->bind_param("iii", $nume, $pret, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Product successfuly updated!";
}
```

[This is my database
**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABYxU.png)

Comment: how you come to know that it not worked? any error or something?

Comment: use $stmt->execute(array($nume, $pret, $id)); or bind_param comment

Comment: Can you add some more details besides "but doesn't work" please? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: I don't get any error.When I  want to click the update button it doesn't work. Just appears the message "Product successfuly upated!"

Comment: It doesn't update.

Comment: Well, to start with something, you aren't really checking if it worked or not. You should place the `$stmt->execute()` inside an if/else statement, since the function returns true/false, and then show success if true or error if false. Having that said, have you checked if the connection works? Consider using `mysqli_connect_errno()`.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Hello , thank you !

Comment: The connections works, and I have executed the stmt in a if statement and it shows that the product was successfuly added but it the database it doesn' update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `echo` `error`

try this

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { 
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "Product successfuly updated!";
} else {
   $_SESSION['error'] = "Product not updated!";
}
```

or if you want to know `error` use this

```
if(!$stmt->execute()) echo $stmt->error;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, doesn't update just appears the message Product successfuly updated.The id variable is in a relationship with id from another table, called serviciiprogramare. It think because of that...

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate2']))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE servicii SET nume =?, pret=? WHERE id=?");
    $nume = $_POST['txtNume'];
    $pret = $_POST['txtCantitate'];
    $id = $_POST['selectProd'];
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $nume, $pret, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Product successfuly updated!";
}
```

assuming $nume & $pret variables contain string.
then change `$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $nume, $pret, $id);` this line to `$stmt->bind_param("sdi", $nume, $pret, $id);`

Comment: pret is float and nume varchar

Comment: @Andreea I've edited my answer. hope it'll work now. visit http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I have tried also this, but my id is in a relationship with another table..is this a problem?

Comment: I guess that's the problem then. when the primary key of a table is updated but it is referenced by a foreign key from another table and the update specific is set to No action. The No action is the default option though you can change it to "ON UPDATE SET NULL" or "ON UPDATE CASCADE". can you provide that other table?

Comment: The other table is called serviciiprogramare and has Serviciiid and Programareid and the servicii.id is in a relationship with serviciiprogramare.Serviciiid

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem cause you're not updating the referential column which is in relation with foreign key. but i can't help but notice that your serviciiprogramare has only two id. so is this table introduced for many to many relationship between servicii table and other?

Comment: what's that other table then? Because in many to many association a new table is introduced to establish the relationship between two entity.

Comment: The other table is programare and has id , date and USERSid.

Comment: everything seems fine. are you sure you've the right privilege to update? did any other of your update statements work? or only this one is causing the problem?

Comment: I have the right to update.I made a insert statement amd it works this.

Comment: As far as i understand and gather reading your comment about the connections working fine i can't assist you further unless i see your database schema.

Comment: I uploaded the image with the database above to the question.

Comment: @Andreea It's working fine for me. As you are using some reserved word i can only suggest you to put backtick(\` \`) around them like `date`, `name`. You can actually put backtick around all database column names.   And in bind_param() you should keep the order as like as the prepared statement. In this case,  `$stmt->bind_param("sdi", $nume, $pret, $id);`
can you tell me what does `$id = $_POST['selectProd']` do? are you sending some servicii_id or any other id?

Comment: I did it.Thank you !

Comment: @Andreea what was the issue? it may help others in future.

Comment: The issue was not here.This code is good. When I called I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind parameters, `i` stands for integer. Which is one of the reasons your query to the database is not working.

If you want to fix this you need to change `iii` in the binding to `ssi`. (This is of course assuming that the first two arguments(?) are strings...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE servicii SET nume = ?, pret= ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $nume, $pret, $id); // ssi
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo 'Failed.';
}
```

Here are a list of argument types for future reference:

- `i` is for integer
- `s` is for string. i.e: "John Doe"
- `d` is for double
- and `b` is for blob.

You can find out more on the **php.net** website!

- [Binds variables to a prepared statement as parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: My variable are string , float an integer .I have tried also sdi or sfi but it doesn't work..

Comment: @Andreea have you made sure that you have included your `$conn` script inside of the same file? Also, that all the credentials are correct

Comment: Yes I have the connection included, i also have  the insert statement and this works.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['btnInsert2']))
 {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO servicii(nume, pret) VALUES (?, ?)");
  //declare parameters
  $n = $_POST['txtNume'];
  $c = $_POST['txtCantitate'];
  
  
  $stmt->bind_param("si", $n, $c);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "Product successfuly added!";
 }